# clone and rename id and names

Tags: jquery

I am trying clone input fields and rename ids and names of Radio buttons and other controls. The cloning works fine but the names are not getting renamed. I want rename radio button names "radio_1" to "radio_2" etc. Here is my code.

```
<form name="form1" id="my_form" method="post" action="">
    <div><input type="text" id="text_1" name="text_1"/> </div>
    <div><label><input type="radio" id=radio1_1" name="radio_1" value="1">Yes</label>
    <label><input type="radio" id=radio1_1" name="radio_1" value="2">No</label>
    </div>

    <!-- Cloned markup-->

    <div><label><input type="radio" id=radio1_2" name="radio_2" value="1">Yes</label>
    <label><input type="radio" id=radio1_2" name="radio_2" value="2">No</label>
    </div>  
      --------------- 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The following code doesn't seem to be working.

```
var settings = {
        newid_ : 0,
        target_: $(this),
        insert_: "before",
        limit_: 0
};
      var srcid = 1;
$(fieldclone).find('input, select, textarea').each(function(){
 var s = $(this).attr("name");          
$(this).attr("name", s.replace(eval('/_'+srcid+'/ig'),'_'+settings.newid_)); 
var s1 = $(this).attr("id");            
$(this).attr("id", s1.replace(eval('/_'+srcid+'/ig'),'_'+settings.newid_)); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use for that sort of thing, and you might be able to adjust it for your application:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.cloneAndIncrement = function(newIndex) {
        var newItem = this.clone();
        newItem.find("[name]").each(function() {
            $(this).attr("name", $(this).attr("name").replace( /\[\d\]/ , "[" + newIndex + "]"));
        });
        newItem.find("[data-valmsg-for]").each(function() {
            $(this).attr("data-valmsg-for", $(this).attr("data-valmsg-for").replace( /\[\d\]/ , "[" + newIndex + "]"));
        });
        newItem.find("[id]").each(function() {
            $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id").replace( /_\d_/ , "_" + newIndex + "_"));
        });
        newItem.attr("id", newItem.attr("id").replace( /_\d_/ , "_" + newIndex + "_"));
        newItem.find("input[name$='.Index']").val(newIndex);
        var entityId = newItem.find("input:hidden[name$='.Id']");
        if (entityId)
            entityId.val(0);
        return newItem;
    };
})($);
```

Note that it is made for ASP.NET MVC applications, hence the expectation of the input with the name `Index`. It also adjusts some unobtrusive validation attributes and zeroes out the ID attribute (since in my application these cloned inputs are for additional items to be inserted into the database).

Note that my convention is to use brackets to keep track of the indexed items. You'd want to change that regex to be something like this (warning, not tested!):

```
newItem.find("[name]").each(function() {
            $(this).attr("name", $(this).attr("name").replace( /\_\d\/ , "_" + newIndex));
```